# jquery Tools validator with overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery-tools

I'm getting some variant behaviour using jQuery Tools form dialog  - i.e. using validator on a form contained in an overlay. Here is my code (should load straight up)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Simple</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
.dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  padding:5px;
  background-color:rgba(178, 168, 79, 0.7);
  border:2px solid #666;
  border:2px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.7);
  -moz-border-radius:6px;
  -webkit-border-radius:6px;
}

form {
  background:#333;  
  padding:15px 20px; 
  color:#eee;
  width:360px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;  
} 

form input {
  border:1px solid #444;
  background-color:#666;
  padding:5px;
  color:#ddd;
  font-size:12px;

  /* CSS3 spicing */
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;  
}

form input:focus     { color:#fff; background-color:#777; }
form input:active   { background-color:#888; }

fieldset {
 border: 0;
}

.error {
  height:15px;
  background-color:#FFFE36;
  font-size:12px;
  border:1px solid #E1E16D;
  padding:4px 10px;
  color:#000;
  display:none;  

  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px; 
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:0;  
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0; 
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0;

  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 6px #ddd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #ddd;  
}

form label {
  display:block;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#ccc;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" name="dlgBtn">Show Dialog</button>
<div class='dialog'>
  <form class='form'>
    <fieldset>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" required="required" />
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
</body>

<script>
$("button[name='dlgBtn']").click(function() {
  $("form")[0].reset();
  $("div").data("overlay").load();
}); 

$("form").validator().submit(function() {
  $("div").data("overlay").close();
  alert("Submitted OK!");
  return false;
});

$("div").overlay({top:180, closeOnClick: true, mask: {color: '#fff', loadSpeed: 100, opacity: 0.5}});
</script>
</html>
```

This code has the following problems (in order of importance to this question) -

1. In Chrome 8.0.552.231, the 'required' validator failure does not stop the form being submitted (it does in FF).
2. In Chrome, the error message is not visible in relation to the dialog, but appears in the document body, and is only visible once the dialog closes.
3. In Firefox 4b7, the validator error appears below the input regardless of any position setting when initialising the validator. It should appear on the right by default.
4. In FF, the form.reset() does not reset the form (it does in chrome). This can be tested by opening the dialog a second time after submitting. At first glance doesn't look to be jquery Tools related, but thought I'd throw it in :).
5. In Chrome , the field border is not initially red (it is in FF)
6. In FF, the field border does not turn blue when selected (it does in Chrome)
7. The error message text for FF and Chrome is different

Other people seeing the same behaviour? Is it possible to fix that code to work as expected, and vaguely the same in both browsers? Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my initial try: [example link](http://jsbin.com/abepe3/2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Simple</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #dialog {
                display: none;
                width: 400px;
                padding:5px;
                background-color:rgba(178, 168, 79, 0.7);
                border:2px solid #666;
                border:2px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.7);
                -moz-border-radius:6px;
                -webkit-border-radius:6px;
            }

            form {
                background:#333;
                padding:15px 20px;
                color:#eee;
                width:360px;
                margin:0 auto;
                position:relative;
                -moz-border-radius:5px;
                -webkit-border-radius:5px;
            }

            form input {
                border:1px solid #444;
                background-color:#666;
                padding:5px;
                color:#ddd;
                font-size:12px;

                /* CSS3 spicing */
                text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
                -moz-border-radius:4px;
                -webkit-border-radius:4px;
            }

            form input:focus     { color:#fff; background-color:#777; }
            form input:active   { background-color:#888; }

            fieldset {
                border: 0;
            }

            .error {
                height:15px;
                background-color:#FFFE36;
                font-size:12px;
                border:1px solid #E1E16D;
                padding:4px 10px;
                color:#000;
                display:none;
                z-index: 9999;

                -moz-border-radius:4px;
                -webkit-border-radius:4px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft:0;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0;

                -moz-box-shadow:0 0 6px #ddd;
                -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #ddd;
            }
            .error p {margin: 0}
            form label {
                display:block;
                font-size:13px;
                color:#ccc;
                padding-bottom: 2px;
            }

            .hidden {display: none}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" name="dlgBtn">Show Dialog</button>
        <div id='dialog'>
            <form id='form'>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input name="name" type="text" required="required" />
                </fieldset>
                <input type="reset" class="hidden" />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        $("button[name='dlgBtn']").click(function() {
            $(":reset", "#form").click();
            $dialog.load();
        });

        // this is the object API and NOT the object itself!
        var $form = $("#form").validator({ position: 'center right' }).submit(function(e) {
            // Now this is the form object
            var form = $(this);

            // client-side validation OK.
            if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                // The ajax call; use the form object above to get the action attr, serialize..etc
                // more: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/server-side.html
                //$.ajax({...})

                // BEGIN: THESE WILL GO IN THE SUCCESS METHOD OF THE AJAX CALL
                alert("Submitted OK!");
                $form.reset();
                $dialog.close();
                // END: THESE WILL GO IN THE SUCCESS METHOD OF THE AJAX CALL

                // THIS IS OUTSIDE THE AJAX CALL
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }).data('validator');

        // this is the object API and NOT the object itself!
        var $dialog = $("#dialog").overlay({top:180, closeOnClick: true, mask: {color: '#fff', loadSpeed: 100, opacity: 0.5}}).data("overlay");

        // Without this, Error messages will remain visible
        $dialog.onBeforeClose(function(){
            $form.reset();
        });

        // This is to keep the error message next to it's corresponding input
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $form.reflow();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: Answers to your questions added
1. In Chrome 8.0.552.231, the 'required' validator failure does not stop the form being submitted (it does in FF).
**It does now**
2. In Chrome, the error message is not visible in relation to the dialog, but appears in the document body, and is only visible once the dialog closes.
**This is because you the overlay has z-index 9998, setting error div to 9999 fixed that**
3. In Firefox 4b7, the validator error appears below the input regardless of any position setting when initialising the validator. It should appear on the right by default.
**I don't know if it's a FF bug (unfortunately I don't hv FF 4), but I've added `{ position: 'center right'` to the validator to insure the positioning**
4. In FF, the form.reset() does not reset the form (it does in chrome). This can be tested by opening the dialog a second time after submitting. At first glance doesn't look to be jquery Tools related, but thought I'd throw it in :).
**Having a hidden reset button will do the job and help the $form variable afterwords**
5. In Chrome , the field border is not initially red (it is in FF)
**It's not red in my FF...**
6. In FF, the field border does not turn blue when selected (it does in Chrome)
**Mostly likely the above two point are Browser (+ OS theme) related**
7. The error message text for FF and Chrome is different
**It's the same here..**

Comment: I've changed the classes to IDs for faster DOM access

Comment: Hey guys, the overlay syntax is wrong. It should be $('#overlay-trigger'.overlay(). By default the overlay selector goes to rel attribute of the trigger. Right now the dialog is the trigger for dialog overlay and that causes it to close when clicking the submit button even if the form validation doesn't go through.

Comment: not exactly, what your are saying is the __defalt__ setup, but @hawkettc setup still true and here is an [example](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/trigger.html) it was closing on submit because of the way he was handling the submit (look at his submit and mine)

Comment: On the second look you're right :). I had the same form submit fix but must have had some other problem closing the dialog. So it wasn't the overlay syntax.

Comment: Thanks @ifaour, great answer. FWIW, FF4b7 still doesn't position the error message correctly to the right, but I'm hoping this is something that jqTools will iron out as FF4 becomes more prevalent. The border colour thing is fairly insignificant, and I had a closer look at the error messages and it looks like Web Forms 2.0 the browsers define their own messages for standard validation attributes, so it is most likely using those. Cheers.

Comment: What was the solution for #1?  Saying "It does now" doesn't help anyone understand what was wrong and how to fix it.