# How to get jQuery Tools validation working in an overlay dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I've got a simple text entry dialog working with jQT overlays -- click a link, an overlay opens with the form, fill out the form, hit submit, and the form gets processed.  I'm now trying to add validation to the form, but the validation never happens.  If I disable the overlay on the link and let the form open in a separate window, validation works properly, so I'm relatively sure I've got the basic validation stuff set up properly.  This no-overlay version is effectively what's happening in http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/index.html -- a page containing a form is loaded, the validation gets set up, and the validation code runs on form submit.

The problem with the overlay version, I think, is that the validation isn't getting set up properly, most likely because the form isn't getting found.  The overlay form doesn't exist until the link is clicked, so the call to validator() can't be in the main page containing the link.  I've tried tacking a SCRIPT tag containing the validator() call onto the end of the form code when it gets created, but that doesn't work.  Nor does calling validator() on the appropriate ID from inside the jQuery code that sets up the overlay form.  In all cases, I'm not seeing any javascript errors showing up in the console.  Arggh.

I would think this is a common usage of jQT forms and validation, but I just can't figure out what's going on here (or not going on here).  Any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: try the approach used here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515269/4530234#4530234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just tap into the `onLoad` event in the overlay:

```
$("#dialog").overlay({
    load: true,
    onLoad: function() {
        $("#form").validator();
    },
    onBeforeClose: function() {
        $("#form").data("validator").reset();
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Added `onBeforeClose` handler to reset the form validation upon closing the overlay.

Additionally, make sure the `z-index` CSS property for errors is *above* the z-index of the overlay.

However, I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to place the call to `validator()` outside of the overlay setup code.

> The overlay form doesn't exist until
>   the link is clicked, so the call to
>   validator() can't be in the main page
>   containing the link

This isn't quite right: If you inspect your HTML with FireBug you'll see that the overlay elements are just hidden, and will get shown and CSS will get applied to the div to make it look like a modal dialog.  The `form` should always exist in the DOM.

Check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/SYPSG/

Comment: This is looking very close -- I still have a few things at my end that aren't there, but it looks promising.  More later...

Comment: @Jim: Good to hear.  Feel free to post any HTML/JS you're having specific issues with.

Comment: @Andrew -- Like I said, very close.  The only problem I'm having, which also exists with your example, is that if you fail to fill out the form correctly, exposing the error divs, and then cancel out of the form by clicking in the page background (or on the close widget in my form), the form goes away but the error divs remain visible.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jim: You should be able to tap into the `onBeforeClose` event of the overlay and call the `reset` method of the form validator.  I've updated my answer and the example.

Comment: Yup -- I thought of this just as I was falling asleep last night, but thanks for saving me the time!  One final question (which should maybe be a separate thread, but whatever: textareas don't seem to work with this validation code.  Am I missing something or do I "just" need to define a custom validator for it?

Comment: @Jim: I am able to get `required` validation working on textareas: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/SYPSG/5/.  Is there another type of validation that's not working for you?

Comment: Note to above: Or does validation only work with INPUT widgets? My form originally used a textarea, but the validation didn't work, and the textarea didn't even show up. ?

Comment: @Jim: That's a good question--I believe `validator` will validate any standard HTML element that accepts user-input, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Sorry -- apparent brainfart at my end.  I'm not sure what was going on, but textareas are validating just fine now.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Jim: No problem! Glad to help--I know jQuery Tools can be a pain sometimes :)

Comment: @Andrew -- at the risk of reopening this: As you might assume, the method you laid out has been working well for me.  But I'm now noticing that, ever so often, the validator seems to not get assigned to the form -- attempts to submit the form fail because the validator can't be found. The page must be refreshed to proceed. It happens rarely, usually when I'm showing the site to other people :) I've been trying, but haven't been able to isolate any causes; are there any chances of a race condition or something getting in the way of the validator getting assigned? Or something else? Thx!

Comment: @Jim: Interesting. Can you duplicate it with a small example?

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, if only I could.  Right now, it's all wrapped up in a bunch of other code, and is hard to split out.  I'm in the process of beating on it; I'll report back if I can get anything reproducible.  In the meantime, it sounds like there's no reason that the method shouldn't work.  Any chance that, under load, the javascript thread running the onLoad happens before the form is ready?  I've got the validator call wrapped in a document.ready handler, so it doesn't seem like that should be happening, but...  Thanks in any case!